# Does that violate the 3NF?

Tags: database, normalization

I need to put `Shipping address`, `Shipping postcode`, `Billing Address` and `Billing Postcode` into one `Customer` table.

Does that violate the 3NF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that violate the 3NF?

*Very* strictly speaking: Yes.

Practically speaking: No.

If you **don't** plan:

- to have dedicated "Address" entities in your database (i.e.: when the address is nothing more than free text attached to a customer record)
- to have a variable amount of addresses per customer (but only the two)
- to have to write a LEFT JOIN for every address you want to select...

...then stick with your design.

Normalizing the address into a separate table is about as sensible as normalizing first and last names into their separate tables just because they tend to repeat. Don't do it.

---

Consider "practical"

```
SELECT
  CustomerId
  CustomerName,
  COALESCE(BillingAddress, ShippingAddress) AS BillingAddress,
  COALESCE(BillingPostcode, ShippingPostcode) AS BillingPostcode
FROM
  Customer
```

vs. "fully normalized"

```
SELECT
  c.CustomerId
  c.CustomerName,
  COALESCE(bill.Address, ship.Address) AS BillingAddress,
  COALESCE(bill.Postcode, ship.Postcode) AS BillingPostcode
FROM
  Customer AS c
  -- join customer-to-address-resolution for billing
  LEFT JOIN CustomerAddress AS custAddrB ON custAddrB.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
                                            AND custAddrB.AddressType = "Billing"
  LEFT JOIN Address         AS      bill ON bill.AddressId = custAddrB.AddressId
  -- join customer-to-address-resolution for shipping
  LEFT JOIN CustomerAddress AS custAddrS ON custAddrS.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
                                            AND custAddrS.AddressType = "Shipping"
  LEFT JOIN Address         AS      ship ON ship.AddressId = custAddrS.AddressId
```

Plus, the latter system gives you the <strike>headache</strike> theoretical ability of having multiple shipping addresses per customer.

The greatest benefit of the latter system is: If they ever change the name of street, all you would need to do is update a single record. In other words: There are no benefits.

Comment: but if he needs to store multiple addresses to a customer he needs to seperate into 3 tables at least... so better do it now, as later

Comment: @reox If he needs a third address, then he can add a few columns. There are hardly ever more than three addresses per customer; there is no benefit in normalizing that. — However. If this was, say, a location based service and *addresses* were the key entity of the system, maintaining them in a separate table and normalizing the addresses per customer (i.e. "check-ins") would be the right thing to do. But not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

yes, because you will create redundancies with these addresses or you need to have NULL values in the database (e.g. when shipping and billing addr are the same) which is forbidden by 3NF. better use something like this:

```
table customer
... | ... | shipping_address_id | billing_address_id |
----+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
 x  |  y  | 23                  | 24                 |
 x  |  y  | 25                  | 25                 |
...

table address
id | address | postcode | city | country |
---+---------+----------+------+---------+
23 | aaaa    | 1234     | foo  | bar     |
24 | sdfsd   | 2345     | sdf  | sdf     |
....
```

now you can get the addresses via join